# PHP Deprecated: Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated

Tags: php, php-8.1

I can't figured out whats wrong with this.

PHP 8.1
PHP Deprecated:  Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated

```
        $request = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        $request['path'] = ( ! empty( $request['path'] ) ) ? $request['path'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is most likely a bug:

```
$foo = false;
$foo['name'] = 'Jimmy';
```

So PHP now warns about it:

> Deprecated: Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated

... and it's likely that the code will fully stop working in future PHP versions.

In your case, the `false` is coming from [parse_url()](https://php.net/parse_url):

> On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return false.

Inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to figure out why PHP fails to parse it as URL. Use a step debugger of, alternatively, `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

On the other side, it isn't entirely clear (not at least without further context) what the goal is. `REQUEST_URI` is going to have two have at most two components, `path` and `query`, and only `query` is optional. The code fragment does not really do anything, unless you run the script in command-line, in which case it'll throw the *Undefined array key "REQUEST_URI*" warning. It can only do something different if you overwrite `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at an earlier stage.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my own question.

```
$request = parse_url( rawurldecode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
```